# Is there any best practice for handling Visual States in .NET Maui Blazor Hybrid?

Tags: bootstrap-5, maui, blazor-hybrid

Is there any best practice for handling Visual States per platform (Android/iOS), per orientation (Portrait/Landscape) and per device type (Phone/Tablet) in .NET Maui Blazor Hybrid like .NET Maui handles with Visual State Manager in xaml files?

For example I have already implementated a logic to support Dark & Light theme with css variables but I need to find a best practice to handle some css properties (e.g. a bootstrap card padding) differently in some cases (per platform, per orientation & per device type).

I thought to implement some custom converter to handle these actions and use it in every .razor page, but is it the best practice?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

By default, the projects we build here are using bootstrap.

`Bootstrap` supports responsive layout, which can already meet your basic needs, we only need to add styles according to the format of bootstrap. If you write a custom converter by yourself, you need to use `@media`, and you have to write a lot of native `CSS` code, the effect of time-consuming and laborious production may not be as good as the effect of `bootstrap`.